# Dynamically generating Operators from XCOM data

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow

I am writing a simple DAG. I want to pull messages from Google Pub/Sub, and then make snowflake queries depending on these messages.
Since there could be several messages, I may have to make several queries.

This is my current code:

```
@dag(
    "on_event_copy_file_into_snowflake",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    schedule="* * * * *",
    max_active_runs=10,
    catchup=False,
    render_template_as_native_obj=True
)
def on_event_copy_file_into_snowflake():
    pull_messages_operator = PubSubPullOperator(
        task_id="pull_messages_operator",
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
        ack_messages=True,
        messages_callback=filter_messages_v2,
        subscription=SUBSCRIPTION,
        max_messages=5,
    )

    snowflake_copy_file_operations = [
        SnowflakeOperator(
            task_id=f"copy_file_into_{schema}",
            dag=dag,
            snowflake_conn_id=SNOWFLAKE_CONN_ID,
            sql=build_copy_into_sql(schema.upper(), table.upper(), filename.upper()),
            warehouse=SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE,
            database=SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE,
            schema=schema,
            role=SNOWFLAKE_ROLE,
        )
        for schema, table, filename in pull_messages_operator.output
    ]

    chain(
        pull_messages_operator,
        snowflake_copy_file_operations,
    )

on_event_copy_file_into_snowflake()
```

The output from the `PubSubPullOperator` is saved on `XCom` automatically, and what I am passing to it is a list of lists which looks like this:
`[[schema, table, filename], ...]`

Something is wrong because the `XComArg` object is not iterable.

I've read about expanding tasks, but can't seem to find something similar for the SnowflakeOperator.